# Inserting an image into a MySQL database using a PHP WebService

Tags: php, android, mysql, blob

I searched a lot about this question but I didn't find any direct answer.

I am programming an Android application that uses SQL to store data. I'm passing SQL query trought a simple PHP Web Service.

The Web service code is

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['user'])) { $user = $_GET['user']; }
if(isset($_GET['pass'])) { $pass = $_GET['pass']; }
if(isset($_GET['query'])) { $query = $_GET['query']; }

if(isset($query)) {
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$pass) or die('Connexion impossible au serveur SQL');
    mysql_select_db('dbi',$link) or die('Impossible de sÃ©lectionner la base de donnÃ©e');

    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Erreur dans la requete : '.$query);
    $count=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    if ($count>0) echo ";";
        for($a=0;$a<count($row);$a++){
            echo $row[$a];
            if ($a<(count($row)-1)) echo ',';
        }
    $count++;
    }

    @mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Everything is working (I in fact only use the webservice to Insert data in the database (I dump the database into a sqlite database to work with it localy)) except when I try to insert a Blob. I get illegal characters, so I try to encode the query but the blob is corrupt.

```
private String executeQuery(String query){
        HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
        String encodedQuery=null;
        try {
            encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(serverURL+"?user="+username+"&pass="+password+"&query="+encodedQuery);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String result = client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally {
        }
    }
```

I execute the query like that

```
executeQuery("INSERT INTO " + DBIDatabase.TABLE_signatures + " (name, job, signature) VALUES ('" + pm.signature.name + "','" + job_id + "','" + new String(pm.signature.sign.imageByteArray) + "')")
```

Original BLOB (As printed by a System.out.println in eclipse):

```
�PNG


������
IHDR�����������d��������fw������sBIT|d�����RIDATx���=��D���oJ~�����DBB���OH��6B�QDP%�]��n�"����ڞ��3��G��};���������������������������������x��8�&������#9lě����۸ݪ8No���N}��؉t9u%�|��ح�jU\��㠽��f��T"��rp,������7_�
�G��]] L�*��������lK?L+P��+��;��x�I�z�r�+ؐ%���q3��ˆS��$��P�V���*���Ѷ�Dҗ$�ڟZ�b�k��'�!".#�����]So�d��-�k1���X��[�a�2�Y/#�;�~�Кx�J2�ڶ�PwݴОf,�ـ�su{��t��O�5��%��:�t�E�W�/2�?$AԸݠj[<��zEy��+�a�Wй��V̚�i��>]Pk��u���,QQM�2�
ɖ<�5�x�
d��R���wJ�����1��C����e�'K�ف�X�{��N�%'����V�ɐ����-���#V����iD|�1��xK��͋�%l�]�g�zXBܩָNP�v�l8�0נ��1�o��4��9��j�Jj*b��q�'U�،{�n`b5�x*�Ӧle�mZ��r%�GS�7G�}�Z�y�e)cyc����3����z�X���Z�����.��

��8s,��s���]~��d�v�GD|����0T�3��X�䴋��:�>�����("~�a�;�k���_s�(u:�ݒ��1�o�~x0��N�.�26Qy s��R��IC��TkaN���->��Ա�dPL�١OJ2��ؗ�N��g,s���..�ߩ�쓒Aq?�_�7��ʲv�c|��ѢHm�,e{S�q�X�l8���j3�ߕ�i�0I�%�*ۜ�s�0�2����<���!�"��u=x���rVK� �����}UE�N��F�E�YD|�#��y��G��/>G�<D����1�#�߈�+�z�m�{�>//@�����P�D��о8Z�1 ��1�z�Ÿ����!����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������P�����'3������������IEND�B`�')
```

Blob in the database:

```
ï¿½PNG


IHDRï¿½dï¿½ï¿½fwsBIT|dï¿½ï¿½IDATxï¿½ï¿½ï¿½=nï¿½@ï¿½ï¿½Qï¿½ï¿½sï¿½4pï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½ N@ï¿½@ï¿½p (4ï¿½iï¿½DB "ï¿½ï¿½Pï¿½bï¿½Zoï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½VZï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xFï¿½ï¿½Ä¥ï¿½`ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Orï¿½ï¿½cLÞ‡$Gï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½~5ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½Wï¿½ï¿½M;`4ï¿½ï¿½?uw*ï¿½ï¿½.Õ¿ï¿½ë‚¹Vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½T"ï¿½|Oï¿½oï¿½`.ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Jï¿½ï¿½nï¿½ï¿½jIï¿½ï¿½=ï¿½Vï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½Nï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½>ï¿½%ï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½Nï¿½ï¿½I.ï¿½Â¤aï¿½ï¿½,Hï¿½ï¿½47ï¿½=:m{ï¿½
e+ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½`.(ï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½$É³ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Å‚ï¿½Xï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)Bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½^ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½T_ï¿½`Pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½,ï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½S@ï¿½~f|Oï¿½uvv)ï¿½u?ï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½`.ï¿½!ï¿½U[#ï¿½zNï¿½ï¿½,ï¿½?tf(7ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Tï¿½sï¿½-.ï¿½ï¿½ÕYË¼Iu_ï¿½`ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½wï¿½dXï¿½~ï¿½Fyï¿½)ï¿½gï¿½.u
ï¿½Yï¿½ï¿½Æ¬`.ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½WAMï¿½ï¿½Zï¿½ï¿½uï¿½m6xLï¿½k;ï¿½}ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½$_rvï¿½ï¿½Nï¿½V(#Lï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½jï¿½ï¿½eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½ï¿½X,ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½>}ï¿½P>è½ºï¿½fLï¿½ï¿½Ô»ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½!væ‚¡ï¿½%yï¿½zï¿½0vï¿½p.OSosï¿½T@ï¿½ï¿½Nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0Lï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ZKï¿½uï¿½Ï±ï¿½9Uï¿½ï¿½@{ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½*Jï¿½YIENDï¿½B`ï¿½
```

If I load back the picture, it's an empty picture, sadly.
Is there something I missed? Is there any other way to pass the Blob to the PHP Web Service?

Thx

Comment: Do you use BLOB column in your MySQL table? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

Comment: Yes, I was using "BLOB" as the type of de column. Base64 was the solution for me, doesn't know why I haven't tried! Thx @Josephus Villarey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Base64-encode your image, then store as String. This ensures that you only use valid characters on your php, database, and wherever.